How can I compose a message as plain text instead of HTML in Outlook on macOS?
I am forced to use Outlook 16.88 for macOS (the "new Outlook") at work, with no other email client being allowed.

How can I compose a message as plain text instead of HTML?
How can I set Outlook to compose as plain text by default?

Confirmation that this is impossible is also an acceptable answer.

Facing the same issues. Since ‘Office Home & Business 2024’, you cannot switch to the ‘Legacy Outlook for Mac’ anymore. I am forced to use the ‘New Outlook for Mac’. With that, as of today (version 16.92), sending E-mails in text/plain is not available.
This was asked/answered several times on Microsoft Answers. I know, Microsoft Answers is not a good resource because there, issues get not merged but even locked over time. Furthermore, some staff members use artificial intelligence to answer questions instead of asking them internally to double-check their answer.
Anyway, I think, there is a duplicate on Apple.StackExchange … I think, we should continue there, when the situation changes or if somebody else finds a workaround.

Please follow these steps:

Open Outlook for Mac and start a new email by clicking on New Email.
In the new email window, go to the Options tab.
In the Format Text group, turn off the HTML toggle to switch to plain text.


Thanks for writing an answer. I don't see any tabs at all in Outlook. I do see an Options button, but clicking it reveals a menu showing only "Change Language" and "Zoom Interface", nothing else.

Did you open a new email window?

The Options tab existed in the Legacy interface, but does not seem to have made it to the Modern interface.
